# Pull a row from SQL database based on if the value of a column is changed

Tags: asp.net, sql

I need to pull a row in a select statement from a SQL database if a certain value in a table is changed.

For example, I have a column called `price` in a `Price` table. If the user changes the value for `price` (through an asp.net app), I want to select that entire row. This is going to be done in a workflow and an email is sent to the user that the row that was changed AFTER it was changed.

Does this make sense? Can someone point me in the right direction of a procedure or function to use? Thanks.

Comment: What does your data look like? Is price a history table? If it is a history table what's the primary key and what's the date field that determines what before and after is?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** --- *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but **NOT** a database product by itself. It would really help to know what actual **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 1):

You could use an SQL trigger to accomplish this.

There is a tutorial (using Price as you described) that shows how to accomplish this here: http://benreichelt.net/blog/2005/12/13/making-a-trigger-fire-on-column-change/

Comment: This looks like the easiest thing to do. There are two tables joined tho. The price is on a contract table which links to a tracking table. I need to get information off of both tables if the price is updated based on information joined from the other table. Is this even possible with a trigger?

Comment: Could I just put this data into a view and then put a trigger on the view?

Answer (score 0):

well, in order to update a row, you'll have to update that row "WHERE uniqueID = [someid]". Can't you simply run a select immediately after that? (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE uniquueID = [someid])

Comment: The workflow is run in  nightly job. I need to run the select in a different stored procedure.

Comment: Ok, then I would add a "LastModified" (or whatever name is most applicable) date field and update it when it gets changed. Then your other SP can update the ones that were updated since "X" date.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your data looks like (or what database this is, it's a little difficult) but assuming you have a history table with a date and an ID that stays the same like this...

```
+----+-------+------------+
| ID | PRICE | CHNG_DATE  |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | 2.5   | 2001-01-01 |
|  1 | 42    | 2001-01-01 |
|  2 | 4     | 2001-01-01 |
|  2 | 4     | 2001-01-01 |
|  3 | 4     | 2001-01-01 |
|  3 | 3     | 2001-01-01 |
|  3 | 2     | 2001-01-01 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

and your database supports `With` and `Row_number` You could write the following

```sql
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                price, 
                chng_date, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY id 
                    ORDER BY chng_date) rn 
         FROM   price) 
SELECT data.id, 
       data.price     new, 
       data_prv.price old, 
       data.chng_date 
FROM   data 
       INNER JOIN data data_prv 
               ON data.id = data_prv.id 
                  AND data.rn = data_prv.rn + 1 
WHERE  data.price <> data_prv.price
```

That would produce this

```
+----+-----+-----+------------+
| ID | NEW | OLD | CHNG_DATE  |
+----+-----+-----+------------+
|  1 |  42 | 2.5 | 2001-01-01 |
|  3 |   3 | 4   | 2001-01-01 |
|  3 |   2 | 3   | 2001-01-01 |
+----+-----+-----+------------+
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05fc0/10)

If your Database supports `LAG()` its even eaiser

```
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                price                   new, 
                chng_date, 
                Lag(price) 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY id 
                    ORDER BY chng_date) old 
         FROM   price) 
SELECT id, 
       new, 
       old, 
       chng_date 
FROM   data 
WHERE  new <> old
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05fc0/16)